# Return head of list recursively prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to return the first element of the list each time the user requests for another value i.e. `List = [1, 2, 3]`, when the program is executed it returns `1`, however, when `;` is pressed (user asks for another value) then `2` is returned and so on, till the list is empty.

Though I have managed to list all values at once, but the key question here is that, how can I wait and let the user decide of he wants another value or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
member( X, List ).
```

This will enumerate the next member of `List` on each `;`. Each call to the predicate will instantiate the next member of `List` in `X` until all of the members are exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

yes there is a built-in function that does that, but I think you should try to write it yourself to better understand Prolog.

```
each_one([A|_],A).
```

one of the elements of a list is its head element.

```
each_one([_|B],X):- each_one(B,X).
```

more elements are in the list's tail. This is the recursive clause.

There are no elements in the empty list, so we don't write anything (though we could write `each_one([],_):- fail.` with the same effect).

Now you can try it:

```
4 ?- each_one([1,2,3],X).
X = 1
```

Prolog shows you the first solution and waits for your response. You press **';'** to continue:

```
      ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
false.
```